# Passing selected items from ListView to another Activity

Tags: android-layout, listview

MainActivity is my class where the user selects the items off the list view. I use the setOnItemClickListener to get the selected items , from this point I dont know how to pass it to the next activity , do i need to use the parcellable interface ? or is there another way just through intents.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Parcelable {

```
ArrayList<String> shoppingList;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
```

ArrayList  selected ;

```
protected MainActivity(Parcel in) {

}

public static final Creator<MainActivity> CREATOR = new Creator<MainActivity>() {
    @Override
    public MainActivity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MainActivity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MainActivity[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MainActivity[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringList(shoppingList);
}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method

    shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(shoppingList, "Eggs", "Yogurt", "Milk", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tide with bleach", "Cascade","candy","Dental Floss","Toothpaste");
    shoppingList.addAll(Arrays.asList("ice cream","hand lotion"));


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoppingList);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int Position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " You Selected  "+((TextView) view).getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            selected = new ArrayList();
            Collections.addAll(selected,((TextView) view).getText());

             System.out.println(((TextView) view).getText());
        }
    });

}

public void checkout(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SelectedItemsControl.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void checkout(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SelectedItemsControl.class);
    intent.putExtra("selected_list", selectedList)
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

In your receiving Activity you need to do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> selectedList = i.getStringArrayListExtra("selected_list");
```

to add items in list do like fallowing

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(shoppingList, "Eggs", "Yogurt", "Milk", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tide with bleach", "Cascade","candy","Dental Floss","Toothpaste");
    shoppingList.addAll(Arrays.asList("ice cream","hand lotion"));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoppingList);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    selectedList = new ArrayList();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int Position, long id) {
           selectedList.add(adapter.getItem(position));]
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: small misunderstanding here, "shoppingList" is the initial list of objects which populates the ListView in the first activity my goal is to get the selected items by the user which I retrieve off the onItemClick listener it is these selected items that i want to send to the next activity , can you help me with that ?

Comment: create a new list of selected item and add the items from shopping list and then send

Comment: my first problem is how to add the selected items off the listener in to the "selected" array List, how do I populate it ?, what method do I use?

Comment: notice in the listener method I have instantiated an arraylist named selected

Comment: selected.add(shoppingList.get(Position));
        System.out.println(((TextView) view).getText());    Once I ADDED these two lines inside the listener my app fails when i click an item in the list

Comment: is there an issue when I delete the main activity xml file which is created on start up and refer the main java class which handled that xml to a new xml which I now want to be the main xml page. i tried adding it to the manifest file but the it is only the java classes which are there.